# Why ngFor loses the data when ngIf changes?

Tags: angular

I've came across very interesting issue. I have following HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="flag" *ngFor="#obj of myArr.gear">{{obj | json}}</div>
```

And in component, I change the flag every 1 sec:

```
 setInterval(()=>{
  this.flag = !this.flag;
  console.log(this.myArr);
 },1000)
```

Now, as you can see [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/4WyayI?p=preview), there are two interesting things that happen when I change the flag:

1. When I change flag for the first time, ngFor seems to be invoked once again, adding `null` to the html.
2. When flag is switched next time, the html changes to `null` only - it seems that angular doesn't recognise the reference to `myArr` anymore.

Do you have any ideas why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have multiple template directives (ngIf and ngFor) on the same repeated element.

You can move the ngIf directive on a parent element:

```
<div *ngIf="flag">
    <div  *ngFor="let obj of myArr.gear">{{obj | json}}</div>
</div>
```

Alternately, you can use the template syntax for ngIf:

```
<template [ngIf]="flag">
    <div  *ngFor="let obj of myArr.gear">{{obj | json}}</div>
</template>
```

[Demo Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/XSVlEMXgrSvPl3j0RmCm?p=preview)

**[Edit]**

In HTML, there is no guaranteed ordering when enumerating HTML attributes.  According to Misko in this discussion, having directive priorities in Angular1 caused a lot of issues, and so it was purposely not included in Angular2:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4792

There is an easy work-around as you can see from my answer above. I doubt, it will ever be supported unless the Angular core team decide to [use their own HTML parser](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4417) to guarantee the ordering.

This means that when multiple template directives exist on the same element the behaviour is undefined. Personally, I think that [ngFor and ngIf placed on the same element should throw an exception](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7315).

Comment: Pixelbits, thanks for Your answer. However,my question concerns the origin of described behavior.